# Where Does Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() Get Its Information?

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2012, ide

I have a TT PowerShell script running as part of a C# project. That script references `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` to get the contents of the PATH variable.

But the data returned includes paths that I need to change, and that do not match the path in Windows itself.

Where does this method get the paths from and how do I change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the [`Windows API GetEnvironmentStrings()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get its data. (The Unicode version.)

Also see this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

To set an environment variable, you can use [this overload of `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx) which lets you specify the Process, User or Machine set.